# OptaPy error when using @inverse_relation_shadow_variable

Tags: optaplanner, timefold, optapy

When using a setup similar to https://github.com/orther/optapy/blob/0240f744f592d964110c86d1054ce63cf8c38452/optapy-core/tests/test_inverse_relation.py#L13. I tried this code as well and it gives the same error.

I get an error:

`org.optaplanner.optapy.OptaPyException: org.optaplanner.optapy.OptaPyException: A problem occurred when wrapping the python problem  Maybe an annotation was passed an incorrect type (for example, @problem_fact_collection_property(str)  on a function that return a list of int).`

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code to reproduce? We'd love to fix this for Timefold Solver Python.